# is it possible to run a shell script from ansible role/file directory?

Tags: shell, ansible, roles, ansible-role

I have a role that needs to run a shell script `test.sh` saved under files directory of the role and my task looks like as follows

I am getting the following error

> name: Execute shell script
>         command: sh test.sh
>
> FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "test.sh"], "delta":
>   "0:00:00.008077", "end": "2019-10-04 14:23:39.800839", "msg":
>   "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-10-04
>   14:23:39.792762", "stderr": "sh: test.sh: No such file or directory",
>   "stderr_lines": ["sh: test.sh: No such file or directory"], "stdout":
>   "", "stdout_lines": []}

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with :

[script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) Module :

```
- name: Execute shell script
  script: test.sh
```

Per Ansible Documentation

- The script module takes the script name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments.
- The local script at path will be transferred to the remote node and then executed.
- The given script will be processed through the shell environment on the remote node.
- This module does not require python on the remote system, much like the raw module.

Comment: I would like to execute a ruby script at remote host, how can I do that?  ruby is already installed at remote. The script is in role/file directory.?